# strange data remains

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone heard or experienced about following phenomenon ?

Using postgresql 9.0.5 on Windows

= table structure =

[parent] - [child] - [grandchild]

I found out a record remained strangely on the [child] table.
This record exists violating the restriction of foreign key.

- these tables store transaction data of my application
- all the above tables have numeric PRIMARY KEY
- all these tables have FOREIGN KEY restriction (between parent and child, grandchild)
- my application updates each record status along with the transaction progress
- my app copies this record to archive tables (same structure, same restrictions)
  once the all status changed to "normal_end".
- then, delete these records when it finished copy them to the archive tables.
- the status of remained record on the [child] table was NOT "normal_end" but "processing".
  but the status of copied data (same ID) in archive table was "normal_end".
- no error reported at pg_log

I felt it very strange...
I suspect that the deleted data might came back to active !?
Can deleted data be active unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

There should never be data that violates a foreign key constraint (except during a transaction with deferred constraints).

A deleted row should stay deleted once the transaction is committed. That's one of the requirements of ACID. However the correct working of PostgreSQL relies on the correct functioning of your os and hardware. When postgresql fsyncs a file it should really be written to disk or a non volatile cache. Unfortunatly it sometimes happens that disks or controllers tell the system the write has finished while it hasn't and is still in a volatile cache. If you have a raid controller with RAM but no battery make sure the controllers cache is set to write-through.

Personally I have seen PostgreSQL have incorrect data once, it had a duplicate row (same primary key) this was after a crash on a windows xp machine (this was most likely a 9.0.x). Windows XP machines are not very reliable running postgresql. They often give strange network errors.

Comment: It's make sense that it might happen if disk or a non volatile cache are not stable. This windows2008R2 is running on VM. I do not know and can't imagine it may happen on the VM...